# iOS: MaterialComponents shadow

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

I want to use the `MaterialComponents` in my `Swift 4` to add shadow to my views but I can't understand how can I use the shadow elevator. I created a class named `ShadowedView` like the [documentation](https://material.io/components/ios/catalog/shadows/shadow-elevations/) with the same implementation, then in the xib I set the UIView subclass to `ShadowedView`. But the build failed with this error `Use of unresolved identifier 'MDCShadowLayer'`. The documentation is not clear for me. Can anyone please explain to me how can I use the `MaterialComponents`?

Comment: Sorry if this is an annoyance but did you install the component and remember the import statement? It sounds like it doesn't have a reference to  'MDCShadowLayer'

Comment: @Brian added pod 'MaterialComponents/ShadowElevations' in my podFile then I copy/paste the class ShadowedView

Comment: @Brian this is what I exactly did

Comment: Sorry missed that part. Did you run `pod install`?

Comment: @Brian I did it

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here was what I was able to figure out.

There was a dependency `MDCShadowLayer`which wasn't included by using `'MaterialComponents/ShadowElevations'`

I changed my Podfile to the following:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'TestMaterialShadow' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestMaterialShadow
  pod 'MaterialComponents'
end
```

Then `pod install`

I'm using swift 3 so what worked for me was to use the class like so:

```
import UIKit

import MaterialComponents

class ShadowView: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return MDCShadowLayer.self
    }

    var shadowLayer: MDCShadowLayer {
        return self.layer as! MDCShadowLayer
    }

    func setDefaultElevation() {
        self.shadowLayer.elevation = ShadowElevation.cardResting
    }

}
```

Note the change in `setDefaultElevation()`
There appear to be other settings such as `ShadowElevation.carPickedUp` etc which you can use autocomplete to explore yourself.

Then I created a UIView using interface builder, set it's class to what I called `ShadowView`, and created an outlet to it, named here as `myView` in the ViewController.

Then in ViewDidLoad:

```
myView.setDefaultElevation()
```

Just as a suggestion, you'd probably save yourself a lot of trouble if you just create your own shadows for your views. Using that Material Library is a lot of dependencies for very little in return

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import whole `MaterialComponnent`.
Simply add pod `MaterialComponents/ShadowLayer` to your pods.